# Cisco Call Manager JTAPI support for SIP protocol

Tags: call, sip, cisco, cucm, cisco-jtapi

I am trying to monitor SIP devices located on Cisco Call manager via JTAPI. I have installed JTAPI plugin and try to run its sample makeCall scenario.
CUCM version : 9.1.2.10000-28

When I list the controlled device addresses of the provider, it only returns devices with SCCP protocol (skinny phones) but not return devices with SIP device protocol. There are already SIP based devices added into the controlled device list of the provider on CUCM.

```
    JtapiPeer peer = JtapiPeerFactory.getJtapiPeer(null);

    /* connect to the provider */
    String providerString = hostname;
    providerString += ";login=" + login;
    providerString += ";passwd=" + passwd;
    Provider provider = peer.getProvider(providerString);

    /* wait for it to come into service */
    final Condition inService = new Condition();
    provider.addObserver(new ProviderObserver() {
        public void providerChangedEvent (ProvEv [] eventList) {
            if (eventList == null) return;
            for (int i = 0; i < eventList.length; ++i) {
                if (eventList[i] instanceof ProvInServiceEv) {
                    inService.set();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    inService.waitTrue();

    for(Address address : provider.getAddresses()){
        System.out.println(address.getName());
    }
```

Is there any other config, etc.. that I need to do in order to list SIP phones as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Which IP Phone model and firmware you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTAPI applications can only control Cisco Unified IP Phone 7900 Series that run SIP, which includes Cisco Unified IP 7970 phones. Which model you are using? 
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/jtapi_dev/9_1_1/jtapidevguide/featsupported.html#wp1148307

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have 7960 and according to this explanation i can not monitor this phone with SIP .

Comment: Is the JTAPi user associated to the 7960 phone and line? Are correct permissions assigned? I normally check the following permissions: Standard CTI Enabled and Standard CTI Allow Control of Phones supporting Connected Xfer and conf. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/admin/8_0_1/ccmsys/accm-801-cm/a08cti.html#wp1070148.